# Duvida - Array php retorno

Tags: php, array, php-7

Sou iniciante em `php`, e me deparei com seguinte problema.
Eu tenho uma função que me retorna um array que vem do banco de dados.

```
$teste = dados($conexao);
```

E faço:

```
print_r($teste);
```

Ele me retorna os seguintes dados:

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [nome] => Maria
        [idade] => 26
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [nome] => Joao
        [idade] => 18
    )
)
```

Agora vem o problema, eu quero adicionar uma das informações em varias diferente, ex:

```
$nomeJoao = $teste[1].nome;
print_r($nomeJoao);
```

Recebo o seguinte erro na tela:

> Warning: Use of undefined constant nome - assumed 'nome' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
>
> Notice: Array to string conversion

Comment: `$nomeJoao = $teste[1]['nome'];` Resolve ?

Answer (score 1):

No `PHP` o ponto "." é utilizado para concatenação e não para referenciar atributos de um array.
Para referenciar uma propriedade em array associativo você precisa passar o nome da propriedade.

```
$teste = [['nome'=>'João', 'idade'=>20], ['nome'=>'Maria', 'idade'=>25]];
print_r( $teste[0]['nome']); // Aqui eu pego o nome do primeiro array
```

Comment: Obg, me ajudou muito!

Answer (score 0):

Em `php`, caso queira referenciar uma posição de um *array* nominal, deve fazer da seguinte forma (considerando seu exemplo):

```
Array (
    [0] => Array (
        [nome] => Maria
        [idade] => 26
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [nome] => Joao
        [idade] => 18
    )
)

var_dump($teste[1]['nome']);
```

> Joao

Answer (score 0):

## Em determinado item

```
$teste[0]['indice'] = 'valor';
```

## foreach para salvar em todos

```
foreach ($teste as $key => $value){
 $value['indice'] = 'valor';
}
```

mais dúvidas para foreach php [foreach php.net](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/control-structures.foreach.php)

Comment: Valeu!! Me ajudou muito!

Comment: marca como aceita e vota ^^